# How do I only generate interfaces of the APIs?

Tags: angular, typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate the interfaces only with OpenApi and their maven plugin *openapi-generator-maven-plugin* but it also generates the full services with it that I don't want/need.

Now I have found the *withInterfaces* propery but when set to true, it **also** generates the API services. So it generates what I want but also the services I don't want.

Here is my pom config:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${openAPIContractsDirectory}/swagger.json</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>typescript-angular</generatorName>
                <output>${openAPIOutputDirectory}</output>
                <configOptions>
                    <ngVersion>7.2.11</ngVersion>
                    <withInterfaces>true</withInterfaces>
                </configOptions>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>variables.ts,configuration.ts,encoder.ts</supportingFilesToGenerate>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What I want is the models, some of the supporting files described in the pom, and **ONLY** the API interfaces (not the completed services).

Would anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

add this inner section to plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
   ......
   ......
   <configOptions>
        <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```